# Low NumberValue does nothing for the script

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

Instead of depending on the Humanoid's health, I decided to go with custom health. The new health goes by value and works well and I wanted to make it where the character froze for a few seconds and then teleported them to a specific Vector3 value.

I tried writing the script differently, but all of them didn't work at all. I even tried to get it to where the player's position was different but that failed as well.

```
--Responsible for healing a player's humanoid's health

-- declarations
local Figure = script.Parent
local Head = Figure:WaitForChild("Head")
local Humanoid = Figure:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
local PlayerHealth = game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character.Data.Health
local Player = game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character.Humanoid



if PlayerHealth.Value < 30 then
    Player.WalkSpeed = 0
    wait(5)
    Player.WalkSpeed = 16
end
```

The script refused to work in general. Even when it was enabled and put in the right place, it never worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood it right, you want to teleport the character to a position when it's health reaches a value lower than 30 after frozing it for a few seconds. Then you should check the PlayerHealth value every time it's value changed by connecting it to a function to catch the moment where it health falls below 30:

```
local Figure = script.Parent
local Head = Figure:WaitForChild("Head")
local Humanoid = Figure:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
local Data = Figure:WaitForChild("Data") --In any case if the data loads after the script runs
local PlayerHealth = game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character.Data.Health
local Player = game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character.Humanoid


PlayerHealth.Changed:connect(function()--Here you check the value every time it changes.
if PlayerHealth.Value < 30 then
    Player.WalkSpeed = 0
    wait(5)
    -- you can add teleportation here.
    --Figure:MoveTo(Position)
    Player.WalkSpeed = 16
end
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some fixes, if this is a server script then change to this:

```
local Figure = script.Parent
local Head = Figure:WaitForChild("Head")
local Humanoid = Figure:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
local Player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(Figure) --It will get the player from his character as server scripts can't access LocalPlayer
local Health = Player:WaitForChild("Data"):WaitForChild("Health")


Health.Changed:Connect(function()
    if Health.Value < 30 then
        Player.WalkSpeed = 0
        wait(5)
        -- Add more code here
        Player.WalkSpeed = 16
    end
end)
```

else if it was a local script then just change this

```
local Player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(Figure)
```

to

```
local Player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
```

Hope it worked, don't forget to select it as a correct answer and please like it =D